# ARKIT - How can I make sure ARKit is calibrated?

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I am making a simple ruler ARKit app in swift 4.

But I came across the problem that sometimes, my measures are a bit or completely off. Which, I think, is probably due to ARkit being badly calibrated and not detecting my surface correctly.

**I currently project 4 points in 3D, and want to make sure the measure I get with them is correct, or at least coherent**. Is there a standard way to do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a decent way of doing this, by having a threshold on the number of FeaturePoints detected in my frame by Arkit.

For example, if `frame.rawFeaturePoints?.points.count` returns something higher than my threshold (I personally use 50, but that mostly depends on the distance you will usually be from your target), I estimate my app is calibrated.

Comment: Nice solution as well, how long does it generally take for ARKit to pass the threshold for your app?

Comment: Well it mostly depends on the distance you are from your target. Obviously, the farther you are, the more the app can detect feature points. So what I actually do is make my threshold depend on the distance, if I'm really close to my object it'll be around 20-30, if I'm far it'll be like 150. I also thought of using ARFrame.worldMappingStatus, wich gives you the "state of exploration of the environment", but I must admit it didn't quite work as expected.

Comment: And to answer your question I would say something around 2-3 seconds on iPhone 8 iOS 12

Comment: Cool. It's a nice way of going about it

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not a standard way but the way I went about it was by performing hit tests every half a second or so until the hit test actually returned something. Once it did, I at least knew the AR had been calibrated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I ultimately tried something slightly different, but your input helped :)